# Docker container not writing to volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to setup ownCloud with Docker and Docker-Compose. To achieve this I have a docker-compose.yml with 3 containers and their volumes.

```
version: '2'

  services:
    nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      volumes:
        - owncloud:/var/www/html
    owncloud:
      build: ./owncloud
      networks:
        - backend
      volumes:
        - owncloud:/var/www/html
        - data:/data
    mysql:
      build: ./mariadb
      volumes:
        - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
        - backend

  volumes:
    owncloud:
      driver: local
    data:
      driver: local
    mysql:
      driver: local

  networks:
    frontend:
      driver: bridge
    backend:
      driver: bridge
```

I also tried it without the data volume. ownCloud could not write to /data or without this volume to /var/www/html/data. The log only shows timestamps whenever I accessed ownCloud. Changing from data:/data to a hosted volume /var/ownclouddata:/data results in no difference.

The Dockerfiles have only one line each: FROM:image

I´ve tried adding RUN mkdir /data, but it didn´t fix anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mount the volumes in the Dockerfile something like this.

```
VOLUME /data
```

Later in your docker-compose file, you can either use a named volume like you did earlier or simply use it like this.

```
/mnt/test:/data
```

Here /mnt/test is your host volume path and /data is your docker container path.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The `VOLUME` directive is unnecessary here; you can bind-mount a host directory without it, and it has some confusing side effects when used in a Dockerfile.