# Docker is not writing to the defined volumes

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and created following files in a large Node project folder:

`Dockerfile`

```Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:16
# Update npm
RUN npm install --global npm
# WORKDIR automatically creates missing folders
WORKDIR /opt/app
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/42019654/15443125
VOLUME /opt/app
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R app /opt/app
USER app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm install
# RUN npx webpack
CMD [ "sleep", "180" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./dist/dockerVolume/app:/opt/app
```

And I run this command:

```bash
docker compose up --force-recreate --build
```

It builds the image, starts a container and I added a `sleep` to make sure the container stays up for at least 3 minutes. When I open a console for that container and run `cd /opt/app && ls`, I can verify that there are a lot of files. `project/dist/dockerVolume/app` gets created by Docker, but nothing is written to it at any point.

There are no errors or warnings or other indications that something isn't set up correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is OS? try using absolute path for your dist location

Comment: Given what you've shown, I'd expect the host directory `./dist/dockerVolume/app` and the container directory to `/opt/app` to be identical (they have the same contents and writes to one appear in the other); you're not actually running anything in the container that would change those contents (only `sleep`); and if you remove the volume mount, the directory is probably empty in the underlying image.  Does this match what you see?  What do you expect to be different?

Comment: Is the result any different if you use `docker-compose` instead of `docker compose`? And can you provide a [mcve] showing the files you expect and actual files seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should move the `VOLUME` declaration to the end of the Dockerfile, because:

> If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded. ([Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes))

After this you will face the issue of how bind mounts and docker volumes work. Unfortunately if you use a bind mount, the contents of the host directory will always replace the files that are already in the container. Files will only appear in the host directory, if they were created during runtime by the container.

Also see:

- [Docker docs: bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)
- [Docker docs: volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

To solve the issue, you could use any of these workarounds, depending on your usecase:

- Use volumes in your docker-compose.yml file instead of bind mounts ([Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose))
- Create the files you want to run on the host instead of in the image, and bind mount them into the container.
- Use a bash script in the container that creates the neccessary files (if they are missing) when the container is starting (so the bind mount is already initialized, and the changes will persist) and after that, it starts your processes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I moved the VOLUME statement to the end of my Dockerfile. And you were right, I did assume that the COPY statement would affect what's inside my host's volume, which is apparently not true, because volume contents are only affected by runtime, not by build statements.

Comment: Glad I could help! This is sure a strange mechanism in docker, but without it a lot of thing would break, so we have to use a workaround.